# How do I check if my search cursor is empty in arcpy?

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I am writing a toolbox for ArcMap using arcpy. For the purpose of parameter validation I want to check if a query returns any matches, using `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()`. I have tried these two approaches:

```
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Table", "Field", "Field = 'Value'")

if not cursor:
   #Do something.

if cursor == None:
   #Do something.
```

In both cases the code in the `if` statement is never executed even if the cursor contains no rows. The [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/SearchCursor/018w00000011000000/) mentions no method like `.count()` or `.empty()`. So how can it be done?

Comment: `SearchCursor` looks to be a collection object. Have you tried `if len(cursor) != 0`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried, but got `TypeError: object of type 'da.SearchCursor' has no len()`.

Comment: Some kind of feedback instead of silent downvoting would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work by counting the number of rows returned by the cursor:

```js
i = 0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("your_table", ["your_fields"], "your_query") as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        i += 1

if i == 0:
    print "No results returned."
```

Note the construction of the cursor, where a list of your fields is the second parameter. Also, use of "with-as" syntax is preferred since your cursor object will be automatically deleted.

Comment: Works like a charm. Surprisingly long for something so simple, but I can wrap it in a function so it won't bloat the main code. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

TomAdair's answer works great, but for completeness sake I thought I should add this slight variation. It avoids looping through the whole search cursor, when I am not interested in the total count but just that it is larger than zero.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("Table", "Field", "Field = 'Value'") as cursor:
   for row in cursor:
      break
   else:
      print "No results returned."
```